# serilog specify property names to ignore them during destructuring

Tags: asp.net, logging, serilog

There is [destructurama.byignoring](https://github.com/destructurama/by-ignoring) to ignore by lambdas.

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByIgnoringProperties<User>(u => u.Password)
    // Other logger configurationg
    .CreateLogger()
```

Also, there is [masking.serilog](https://github.com/evjenio/masking.serilog) to mask by property name

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByMaskingProperties("Password", "Token")
    .CreateLogger()
```

is there a package to ignore properties by property names.

Comment: What's your use case? perhaps sharing it might prompt a creative suggestion (I'd consider a PR to destructurama, but that does not look like a high traffic maintained thing so it might be better to avoid going down that road in the first instance)

Comment: @RubenBartelink I have a project with hundreds of request models, so I don't want to check all of them and manually ignore properties. I just want to declare property names to be ignored.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fork the destructurama thing or do a PR then
Perhaps start by posting an issue referencing this and asking whether the owners/maintainers would consider such a feature to be a useful addition to either?